# How can I copy resolved dependencies to a new location, into dynamically created directories based on the dependencies details

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java application that requires dependencies to be stored in specific locations (that is, it's not enough for gradle to just resolve them and add them to the classpath).  This in an unfortunate application design, but something I cannot change.

I am using Gradle (required) to resolve the dependencies as follows:

```
configurations {
  myDeps
}

dependencies {
  myDeps group: 'foo.bar', name: 'baz', version: '1.0.0'
}
```

And copying them to a location using a Copy task:

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.myDeps
  into "copyLocation"
}
```

This however, results in all dependencies stored flat in the "copyLocation", like: `copyLocation/baz-1.0.0.jar`
when what I actually required is them stored in a structure like: `copyLocation/foo/bar/baz/1.0.0/baz-1.0.0.jar`

I have tried to use the `eachFile` method to dynamically set the path, but the `FileCopyDetails` passed to the closure only contains references to the filename (`baz-1.0.0.jar`).

The `toString()` of the `FileCopyDetails` contains the explicit path to where the dependency was retrieved from (and therefore all the info I need), but regex will be flaky given it can from from a number of sources, and will differ across user's machines e.g:
It might be coming from my local Gradle cache

```
C:\Users\myUser\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\foo.bar\baz\1.0.0\15d703651587fad0bb9d5s8c7b28d8b3b6a91x99\baz-1.0.0.jar
```

or maybe my local Maven repository

```
C:\whatever\path\to\myMavenRepo\foo\bar\baz\1.0.0\baz-1.0.0.jar
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you give me a rough design of Application what you want!!! like download dependency and copy that `dependency` to a `specific folder` not in `lib`, but somewhere else

Comment: @DupinderSingh - I'm not really sure what you're saying, or what the excess exclamation marks are for. As I stated in my question, my application requires dependencies (JAR files) are in specific locations - I cannot change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy the artifacts (jar files) of your declared dependencies into a folder that mirrors a Maven layout.

One way to do that is using `Configuration.resolvedConfiguration` and loop over the artifacts. Here is an example (using the Groovy DSL):

```
task copyDeps(type: Sync) {
    configurations.myDeps.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
        def id = it.moduleVersion.id
        def groupFolders = id.group.replaceAll(/\./, "/")
        from(it.file) {
            into "$groupFolders/${id.name}/${id.version}/"
        }
        into "$buildDir/copyLocation"
    }
}
```

Note that I used a `Sync` task instead of `Copy` to ensure old files will be removed from the folder in case they are removed from the configuration.

Comment: Thank you @Bjørn Vester - I ended up discovering the ```resolvedConfiguration``` and it's sub-objects that eventually got me all the information I required (group/name/version/extension).  Your solution is slightly less wordy than what I came up with though, so I think I'll end up with something in between. I'll also make use of the ```Sync``` task, for the exact reason you stated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Download the your jar and install the jar on your location using this command -

```
Plug in repositories : add repositories in your grade build file.
command  : mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Grade : gradle install -Dmaven.repo.local=the/path/of/the/folder

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://yourrepositoryserverLocation/"
    }
}

Dependencies : add dependency in your grade build file.

compile group: 'mx.interactivetv', name: 'interactive-baz', version: '1.2.8'
```

Comment: Hey mate. I'm managing this project using Gradle (per my examples), not Maven.

Comment: please now you can check and confirm.

Comment: I have hundreds of dependencies to resolve, and I have no intention of using maintaining Maven config as well as my Gradle project. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay according to my understanding from the question, this following gralde task can help you

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from("$buildDir/outputs/jar") {
        include "*.jar"
    }
    into file("${rootProject.projectDir}/CustomFolderPath/")
}

build.finalizedBy(copyDependencies)
```

please let me know if it helped or need more assistance!

Comment: I'm not sure how the ```JAR```s are getting into ```"$buildDir/outputs/jar"``` in the first place, and the ```CustomFolderPath``` needs to be set dynamically based on dependency metadata.  I have accepted an answer for this question now. Thanks anyway.